# Adding permissions for only one type of things - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with wordpress custom post type posts.Now i work on restaurant Directory theme.Suppose i have admin access and i want to make some persons as `restaurant manager` . They can add their restaurants all info.Now i have other options i.e: `customer` these customer can add reviews of any restaurants.And i (`admin`) can see all reviews of all restaurants.But `restaurant manager` can see only the reviews of their perspective `restaurants`.Is it possible in wordpress?Here `reviews` is my custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [roles and capabilities docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

You could use a WordPress capability manager plugin as [User Role Editor](https://www.role-editor.com) or [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/) to add a specific capability to a role.

Comment: Actually i want to make it integrated in theme

Comment: @designerDepot Could you provide code you tried with add_cap https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap and i will try to help.